# Laravel RESTFUL Query String: Handling "OR" Conditions

Tags: rest, laravel

Say for example I have a Dog resource and I want to query this resource using some RESTful API that I am creating.

How would I produce and consequently handle a query with an "OR" condition. For example:

`http://url/dogs/?color=brown|black`

Would the above be a valid URL to request all dogs that are brown or black and how would I handle this with Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array:

```
http://url/dogs/?color[]=brown&color[]=black
```

Then use the array in your code:

```php
$colors = Input::get('color');

$dogs = Dog::whereIn('color', $colors)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty straight forward.

First use `Input::get()` to get the value and then use explode

```
$color = Input::get('color');
$colors = explode('|', $color);

// results in array('brown', 'black');
```

About the pipe character in an URL in general. It is valid but just *might* cause problems somewhere. Maybe a simple hyphen works better `color=brown-black`. Although I have to admit, I like the look of the pipe more...

Comment: Thanks for that! I just Googled it and yeah it does seem that the pipe character isn't a good idea. Given your response which does solve the problem, does this mean that laravel has no in built way to handle OR conditions in query strings? Is this how other REST APIs handle OR requests?

Comment: AFAIK Laravel has no way to do that and I would be very surprised if it had. I've seen many different implementations. There's definitely not one best way. Just do what feels right to you :)